# Setting up SDL on Eclipse with Cross G++ Linker on OSX

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, linker, sdl

I have looked around on the internet, but have not come across anything similar to the issue I am facing. In the project properties on the C++ build settings, the linker listed is "Cross G++ Linker." I have tried multiple methods for Mac on the internet, but none of these work as I am still getting the fatal error that SDL.h cannot be found. Does anybody know how to set this up properly with this linker?